# Using cookies to stay logged in using php

Tags: session, authentication, android-studio

So I want to create an application that needs the user to log in.
So far I managed to log in, but everytime I close and re-open the app, it prompts the user to log in again.
In my Login.php code this is what happens when login succeeds:

```
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "You have been succesfully logged in";
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
die(json_encode($response));
```

I am using android studio for this application, and my idea was to CheckSession inside the onCreate of the Login page.
If session exists for user_id --> skip login page.

Can someone please help me.
How can I make android studio check if user is logged in?